# how to call google places api without providing current location latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

i'm using google places api. their pre-requisite is latitude and longitude of the current location, so i can only search places within radius of 500. question is how to call places at London if my current location is Australia. thanks!

Comment: If you wanted to get any particular location places so instead of the current location you need to pass London location lat. & lng. Or may be you can enter location name from the user and pass that lat. & lng. to map.

Comment: The "pre-requisite" is a latitude and longitude, doesn't need to be the current location (although the example might use that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have successfully search places outside of my current location without latitude & longitude restriction using google place autocomplete api. thanks for all the comments!